# Unable to install ubuntustudio fonts

Tags: 14.04, apt, fonts

I am trying to install the ubuntustudio-font-meta using apt but nothing I do seems to make them install.

The problem is I just installed them last week on another machine but on this it fails with the following error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntustudio-font-meta : Depends: fonts-larabie-deco but it is not installable
                          Depends: fonts-larabie-straight but it is not installable
                          Depends: fonts-larabie-uncommon but it is not installable
                          Depends: gsfonts-other but it is not installable
                          Depends: t1-xfree86-nonfree but it is not installable
                          Depends: ttf-xfree86-nonfree but it is not installable
                          Depends: ttf-xfree86-nonfree-syriac but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing these fonts separately but the all failed. For exmple when installing fonts-larabie-deco I get this error:

```
Package fonts-larabie-deco is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I am not sure what sources it requires and I couldn't find anything online.

I am trying to install them on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: @RedSerpent So it worked?

Comment: @RedSerpent As you're a reputation 101 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**